# SQL Server 2016 replication between Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016

I've been asked to set up SQL Server 2016 replication between a development PC running Windows 10 Home and Windows Server 2012 R2. Both run developer versions of SQL Server 2016.

I have found this tutorial: [Replication Tutorials SQL Server 2016 and later](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337389.aspx)

This is when I realised that the Windows 10  Home edition does not allow you to create extra users and groups, and in order to do so I would need to spend another £120 to upgrade to Windows 10 Pro.

I've never set up server replication at all, my question is:

- Is it possible to setup replication between those operating systems and SQL Servers Dev Editions?

I thought I ask before spending the money just in case it is not possible or I will hit ridiculous amount of problems doing it.

I tried finding anything on that online, to no avail. The [Editions and Supported Features for SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) do not mention SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition and the only version from that list that supports Windows 10 is SQL Server 2016 Standard.

Comment: Replication is a deprecated feature in SQL Server 2016 and will be [removed in future versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143550.aspx). I would start looking at Availability Groups.

Comment: @hot2use Replication itself is not deprecated, just the ability to replicate between 2016 and pre-2012 instances. (And if MS followed their usual definition of "deprecated", that scenario would be listed not as deprecated but as "discontinued/unsupported, but may still work".)

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms143506.aspx shows SQL 2016 Dev as supported on Win10 Home, and I don't know of any explicit feature limitations--though you are right in general that you're limited to what the OS supports.

Have you tried to set up replication using the built-in service logins? I believe the instructions around adding Windows logins are for security best practice, which may not be an issue for a dev environment.

Comment: Hey @T.H. I haven't tried that yet, I didn't even know that you could do that. Will give it a go later on today or tomorrow and will report back here. Thanks!